# How do i get the maximum valued label when using a softmax activation function in the output layer of neural network?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, softmax, activation-function

in a model I have trained I am applying softmax function in the output layer of the neural network. the output has 41 categories and I want to fetch the label with max value and the value itself ..i. e in the output. 41 diseases for a set of inputs ....the softmax predicts for all the diseases but I want to print the disease with maximum probability along with the probability how do I do it?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? Do you have example code that you are writing?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by simply using the `np.argmax()` function :

For example, to get the index of the disease with maximum probability of your first test example :

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
print(np.argmax(predictions[0])  #output the index of the disease with max proba
                                 #for example N#0
```